# ember js view error Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

Tags: ember.js

Currently I have this code

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.user = Ember.Object.create({
  people: customers
});

App.editRowView = Ember.View.create({
  template:"editRowModal"
});

App.userView = Ember.View.extend({
  edit:function(e){
    console.log(this.content.id);
    App.editRowView.append();
  }
});
```

My view goes as follows

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="editRowModal">
    <div class="modalBox" id="modalBox">
        <span class="sprite closeToolTip"></span>
        <h4>Restart</h4>
        <div class="cont">

        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <a class="cancelSendNotification">cancel</a>
            <a class="primary" id="restartCustomer">ok</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

I have a button on the page that has the edit propertied binded to it on its click. Every time I click the button I can console.log the id of my model but I can't seem to make my view show in the dom. I'm not sure what is happening since my App.editRowView.template is pointint to the data-template-name attribute of my view template and in theory it should just bind... any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing

```
App.editRowView = Ember.View.create({
  template:"editRowModal"
});
```

to

```
App.editRowView = Ember.View.create({
  templateName:"editRowModal"
});
```